# Windows Xp - entry point gettickcount64 could not be located kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, c, curl, visual-c++, libcurl

I have created http POST request using Curl library (Cpp Programming).

**Configuration:**

```
Visual studio 2017
Platform Toolset : Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)
```

When I run exe on windows xp system, it's throwing following exception:

```
the procedure entry point gettickcount64 could not be located kernel32.dll
```

My code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "xxxxxx");

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\t\"UserName\":\"abc\", \n\t\"Password\":\"xyz\"\n}");
    CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

So, how to solve that error? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you built `libcurl` yourself?or have used prebuilt ones?

Comment: I have used prebuilt.

Answer (score 4):

From [[MS.Learn]: GetTickCount64 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64) (*Requirements* section):

> **Minimum supported client**               Windows **Vista** [desktop apps | UWP apps]

Alternatives:

1. Don't run it on *XP* (*MS* no longer supports it), switch to *Vista* (or newer) that has the function in *Kernel32.dll* (this is the most obvious one)
2. If you're using a downloaded *cURL* (prebuilt) library:

   - Rebuild it using the same tools as your *app*, and **either**:

     - `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501`
     - Pass `/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` to the compiler
3. If you're including the *cURL* sources directly, specify the above compiler flag into your *VStudio* project ([[MS.Learn]: /D (Preprocessor Definitions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2017))
4. While browsing the official download page ([[curl]: Releases and Downloads](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)), **I found** [[WinampPlugins]: curl 7.53.1 for Windows](https://winampplugins.co.uk/curl).
   So, apparently it's possible to download a binary that is *XP* compatible. It's an older version, and *032 bit* only (*064 bit* *XP*s are rare anyway), but **it can get you going**

Comment: I'm trying to run a game on XP and i get the same error as this post's title. After some search, I realized that there's a file named libcurl.dll in the game's folder, which calls this function. I tried to download this XP compatible binary, but I don't know what to do then. Could you help me?

Comment: @Kobayashi: You need to overwrite (back it up first) the *libcurl.dll* from your project that calls this function with the one you downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have used pre-built version of `libcurl` from downloads section of site. I never had this problem myself, but since `GetTickCount64` is Windows Vista+ API, it means that they have not compiled library with Windows XP compatibility.

Try to build library yourself and then see if you program runs with any problem or not.